# Get Caller Information for property in c#

Tags: c#

Wanted to know how to get caller information for a property

for a method it is easy

```
public void TraceMessage([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "") {
    Console.Println(memberName);
}
```

and you will get who called the method.

I want the same thing for a property

```
public MySqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
```

I tried getting the caller name by calling a function from the getter like this

```
public Connection connection { get { TraceMessage()
return _someVariable;} 
set; }
```

But by doing this the TraceMessage prints

> Connection

as the method name

Is there any way to either pass a parameter to the getter or something else to achieve this?

Comment: You always can access the Callstack. but be sure that you really need it, because it may cause performance issue. Maybe you could redesign your software.

Comment: like that:       var t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
      var callingMethodName = t.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;

Comment: Ya the thing is I really need it without causing any performance degradation. Hence would avoid using stackTrace. any other idea?

Comment: Redesign it so that you expose the connection through a GetConnection() -method and then use CallerMemberName. If you insist on using properties you need to use stacktrace. Otherwise I would suggest adding a good logging framework into your design and forget these types of design choices.

Comment: sorry, no. the [callerMemberName] is so fast because it is a compiler feature. that menas in IL it is a normal parameter call with a constant string, because the c#-compiler inserts the name of the function if there is no explicit value. In properties the compiler has no way to do similar. So If you really need it, you have to do runtime analysis via stacktrace :-(

Comment: Finally ended up changing the design a bit and using caller information due to its performance. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

You get the name of the property because it is the previous method in the stack trace. To trace it in the property you can use System.Diagnostics.StackTrace:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
.
.
public Connection connection 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
        return _connection;
    } 
}
```

[Example can be found in this link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-calling-method-name/)

Furthermore if you want to create a separate method for that you can create a method that gets the frame before the frame. The frames are indexed so that current method/property frame is 0, the caller is 1, caller of the caller is 2 and so forth.

```
public void LogCaller()
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(new StackTrace().GetFrame(2).GetMethod().Name);
}
```

And then call that method from the property.

Comment: I would only use this  to trace a problem if all else fails, not as a good design example though.